# Can I go offline after starting a game that needs Games for  Windows Live?

Tags: games-for-windows-live

I am planing to play `Batman Arkham City` or `Fable III` on a trip by train on my laptop. Both are `Games for Windows Live` games.

The games already have save games that I would like to continue playing.

I have mobile UMTS USB stick, that allows me to connect to the internet, but I'm afraid this won't hold the connection while going 150 km/h :)

Can I safely disconnect from the Internet after I started the game or do these games require to be always on (will it affect my ability to save a game, gain achievements)?

Comment: Have you tried it?  Just connect using the device, load up the game, then unplug the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it worked for me (using Steam and GFWL), without the need to change anything for Batman Arkham Asylum

The first time

- I started the game with Steam and GFWL (being online the whole time)
- After a few minutes I lost connection and disconnect
- I played for roughly 4 hours and got the achievements for steam and GFWL (I got the popup
- At some point I exited the game
- When I tried to restart Arkham City Steam told me that it couldn't sync my savegames (because I was still offline) and playing the game now may result in losing my progress
- Consequently I didn't start the game
- Later when I could go online, I started Steam again in online mode, started Arkham City and saw that my progress was saved and everything was good :)

The next time I was offline the whole time

- I started steam in offline mode
- and Arkham City just started normally and GFWL didn't complain about being offline

<strike>In Conclusion it seems that you can play one session completely offline but need to be online between sessions, so that your progress is saved.</strike>

Edit:
According to the comment my assumption was false. Therefore it really seems that you can play GFWL games offline (via steam?) without any problems.

Comment: Your conclusion is incorrect, the warning Steam gave refers to loss of data due to hardware malfunction, not saves magically disappearing if you play the game offline twice in a row.

Comment: @kotekzot good to know, the message was so short and I was afraid of losing 4hours of gameplay.

Comment: Steam backs up your savegames to its servers.  The message was warning you that your savegames wouldn't be backed up until you came back online.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't create an offline profile I think you can't continue the online saves...

I'll explain:

- Online profile = everything gets recorded but you need internet to play it.
- Offline profile = you can save and all but it's not recorded to the Internet and you can play it everytime with Internet access or without it.

Answer (score 0):

You can play offline, you will not  however unlock achievements in offline mode. If you have saves on your online profile you will need to copy it out of the folder labeled your online handle to the root of the folder this depends on where the game stores the saves.

Apparently the above method works now only on old Games for Windows Live games. Batman Arkham City apparently has the save game data signed now. So you would not be able to do the above method. Doing this for Fable III should work however.

This [post](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2331974) on steam talks about how the saves are handled.